# How to populate the Author name and Date automatically in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet which is acessed by a team of 5 members, put in a shared folder. Tracking the changes over the spreadsheet becomes difficult over time.

I would like to achieve the following.  The Excel has around 8 columns (Only Sheet 1) with more than 250 rows. I would like to add another 2 columns, say  Owner (Column 9) and Last Update (column 10) to Sheet1.

Owner - Column 9 - Team Member Name, whoever make the change to that row

Date  - Column10 - Current Date and time whenever the last update made to that row.

Please suggest me the VBA code to automatically populate the Column 9 and Column 10.

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried and we'll help you fix any problems. See [ask] for more info.

Comment: I'm new to VBA coding. nothing has tried yet.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** - Changed row = ActiveCell.row to row = Target.row (allows for if you are no longer on the same row)

Something like this should work. Obviously you may want to consider adding some error handling and perhaps further validation if you only want to do the update if certain fields are changed etc. but this certainly covers the basics:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' declare constants and variables
    Const owner_col As String = "I"
    Const date_col As String = "J"
    Dim row As Double
    Dim owner_addr As Range
    Dim date_addr As Range

    ' initialise
    row = Target.row
    Set owner_addr = Range(owner_col & row)
    Set date_addr = Range(date_col & row)

    ' check that the update is not to the fields you want to update to avoid infinite loop
    If Target.Address <> owner_addr.Address And Target.Address <> date_addr.Address Then
        ' set values
        owner_addr.Value = Environ("username")
        date_addr.Value = Now()
    End If

   ' free up the memory
   Set owner_addr = Nothing
   Set date_addr = Nothing

End Sub
```

This needs to be added to the sheet that you want the changes to be tracked in (i.e. not a module or the whole workbook). Let me know if you have any questions.

The Environ("username") gets the username from the Windows environment variable.